# Como pesquisar pelo valor selecionado em MySQL/PHP e HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde!

Como fazer com que se faça uma `SELECT`que retorne o resultado apenas para o valor preenchido no formulário `HTML`?
Por exemplo, se alguém preencher o campo VIAGEM que retorne todos os valores que contenham a viagem preenchida. Ou se alguém preencher o CNPJ, que retorne todos os valores com o CNPJ preenchido. Mas também, se preencherem os dois campos, que retorne os valores que contenham a VIAGEM e o CNPJ informados.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>                 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>VERIFICACAO DE CARGA</title>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFF0">
<?php
$stat=null;
if (isset($_POST["status"])){
 $stat = $_POST ["status"];
}
?>
<form id="localizacao" name="localizacao" method="post" action="temp.php" onsubmit="return true;">
  <table width="100%" border="1">
      <tr><div align="center"></div></tr>
   <tr><th colspan="5" align="center" valign="top"><h2>Pesquisa</h2></th>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CNPJ:</td>
      <td width="835"><input name="CNPJ" type="text" id="CNPJ" size="20" maxlength="14" />
        <span class="style1">*</span> <span class="style3">somente n&uacute;meros</span></td>    
    </tr> 
 <tr>
 <td width="156">Selecione o STATUS:</td>
  <td><select name="status" id="status">
      <option value="0"<?=($stat == '0')?'selected':''?>>Recebido</option>
     <option value="1"<?=($stat == '1')?'selected':''?>>Em trânsito</option>
     <option value="2"<?=($stat == '2')?'selected':''?>>Encerrado</option>
     </select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 VIAGEM:
 </td>
 <td width="835"><input name="VIAGEM" type="text" id="VIAGEM" size="20" maxlength="14" />
 </td>
 </tr>
    <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><p>
        <input name="pesquisar" type="submit" id="pesquisar" value="Pesquisar" /> 
        <br />
          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar!" />
          <br />
          </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Lista cada documento de acordo com o CNPJ e o STATUS-->  
<?php 
 //Pega o valor do CNPJ e do status escolhido na página anterior
 $CNPJ=null;
 $STATUS=null;
 $VIAGEM=null;  
 if (isset($_POST["CNPJ"])){
  $CNPJ = $_POST ["CNPJ"];
 }
 if (isset($_POST["status"])){
  $STATUS = $_POST ["status"];
 } 
    if (isset($_POST["VIAGEM"])){
  $VIAGEM = $_POST ["VIAGEM"];
 } 
 
 include("conexao.php");
 //Faz a consulta de acordo com o CNPJ e o status 
 
 $sql_dtc = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT * FROM DTC WHERE DTC_CGC='$CNPJ' AND DTC_STATUS='$STATUS' AND DTC_NUMVGA='$VIAGEM'");
 
 echo '<table width="100%" border="1">';
 echo '<thead><tr>';
 echo '<th align="center">CNPJ</th>';
 echo '<th align="center">Data rec</th>';
 echo '<th align="center">Tipo Doc</th>';
 echo '<th>N&ordm; Doc</th>';
 echo '<th>Quant. Vol</th>';
 echo '<th>Processo</th>';
 echo '<th>Loc. Ent.</th>';
 echo '<th>Fornec</th>';
 echo '<th>Status</th>';
 echo '</tr></thead>';
 
 echo '<tbody>';
 while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_dtc)) { 
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_CGC"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_DATREC"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_TIPDOC"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_NUMNFC"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_QTDVOL"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_PROCES"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_CDRDES"].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$aux["DTC_FORNEC"].'</td>';
  if ($aux["DTC_STATUS"]==0){
   echo '<td>'.'Recebido'.'</td>';
  }
  elseif ($aux["DTC_STATUS"]==1){
   echo '<td>'.'Em trânsito'.'</td>';
  }
  else{
   echo '<td>'.'Encerrado'.'</td>';
  }
  //echo '<td align=center><a href=edita.php?cnpj='.$aux['DTC_CGC'].'&tipdoc='.$aux['DTC_TIPDOC'].'&doc='.$aux['DTC_NUMNFC'].'><img src=img/editar.png></a></td>';   
  echo '</tr>';
  }
 echo '</tbody></table>';


?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço muito bem a API da `Mysqli`, mas eu concatenaria a `SQL` de acordo com a consulta e adicionaria numa outra variável os parâmetros que vou usar para a consulta. Depois executaria com um `bind_param` para garantir a segurança da consulta.

Deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM DTC WHERE ';

$parametros = [];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM DTC WHERE 1 = 1";

if (isset($_POST["CNPJ"])) {

    $sql .= " AND DTC_CGC=?";

    $parametros[] = $_POST["CNPJ"];
}
if (isset($_POST["status"])){

    $sql .= " AND DTC_STATUS=?";

    $parametros[] = $_POST["status"];
}   
if (isset($_POST["VIAGEM"])){

    $sql .= " AND DTC_NUMVGA=?";

    $parametros[] = $_POST["VIAGEM"];
}   

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($cx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($cx));

call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $parametros);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($cx));

while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) { 
    //...
}
```

Comment: Esse código está dando o erro: "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on null in rastreamento.php:210 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in rastreamento.php on line 210.

Comment: @Marvin eu editei o código do colega Wallace, veja se funciona ou se retorna algum erro especifico.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o código retornou os Warning's:  "mysqli_prepare() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in rastreamento.php on line 195" e "mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in rastreamento.php on line 195". Também não funcionou.

Comment: @Marvin ajustei a resposta, troque `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql) or die(mysqli_error());` por `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($cx, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: @Marvin era um AND que estava sobrando ali, removi a parte desnecessária, veja a resposta agora.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, agora dá esse warning e não funciona: "mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in rastreamento.php on line 228".

Comment: @Marvin pronto, ajustado no código ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, está dando os Warning's: "Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in rastreamento.php on line 230", "Warning: Parameter 3 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in rastreamento.php on line 230" e "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Invalid type or no types specified in rastreamento.php on line 230". É nessa linha: `call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $parametros);`.

Comment: @Marvin vou testar aqui

Answer (score -3):

No caso de seu exemplo o nome da sua página tem que ser temp.php.

Porque da forma que está fazendo vai fazer a requisição para própria página.

Levei em consideração que o status sempre terá valor de acordo com o exemplo.

Realize a s modificações abaixo que se o restante estiver correto vai fazer o precisa.

```
$CNPJ=null;

$STATUS=null;
$VIAGEM=null;       
if (isset($_POST["CNPJ"]){
    $CNPJ = $_POST ["CNPJ"];
}
if (isset($_POST["status"])){
    $STATUS = $_POST ["status"];
}   
if (isset($_POST["VIAGEM"])){
    $VIAGEM = $_POST ["VIAGEM"];
}   

$STATUS = $cx->real_escape_string($STATUS);

$condicao = '';

if( $CNPJ != '' AND strlen($CNPJ) == 14 )
{
  $CNPJ = $cx->real_escape_string($CNPJ);
  $condicao = " AND DTC_CGC = '$CNPJ'";     
}

if( $VIAGEM != '' )
{
  $VIAGEM = $cx->real_escape_string($VIAGEM);
  $condicao .= " AND DTC_NUMVGA='$VIAGEM'";     
}

$sql_dtc = mysqli_query($cx, "SELECT * FROM DTC WHERE DTC_STATUS='$STATUS' $condicao ");
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: -1 . Tá Bem fácil fazer um SQL Injection aí, hein.